# tabNavigator screens animation when changing tab

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

I used tabNavigator in my app when I change screen to screen, I want the screen animated, i.e: left to right or right to left...
I have searched google some, but I just saw the options for stackNavigator. Is there anyone who knows any way how to make it? Thank you so much! <3

Answer (score 1):

search for `react navigation animation` in Documentation of `reactnavigation`